# Bin Packing algorithm - Practical Variation

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, optimization, bin-packing

I am trying to solve a weird bin packing problem. A link for the original problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537335/strange-but-practical-2d-bin-packing-optimization)
(sorry for the long question, thanks for your patience)

I am re-iterating the problem as follows:
I am trying to write an application that generates drawing for compartmentalized Panel.

I have N cubicles (2D rectangles) (N <= 40). For each cubicle there is a minimum height (minHeight[i]) and minimum width (minWidth[i]) associated. The panel itself also has a MAXIMUM_HEIGHT constraint.

These N cubicles have to be stacked one on top of the other in a column-wise grid such that the above constraints are met for each cubicle.

Also, the width of each column is decided by the maximum of minWidths of each cubicle in that column.

Also, the height of each column should be the same. This decides the height of the panel

We can add spare cubicles in the empty space left in any column or we can increase the height/width of any cubicle beyond the specified minimum. However we cannot rotate any of the cubicles.

```
OBJECTIVE: TO MINIMIZE TOTAL PANEL WIDTH.
```

MAXIMUM_HEIGHT of panel = 2100mm, minwidth range (350mm to 800mm), minheight range (225mm to 2100mm)

As per the answer chosen, I formulated the Integer Linear Program. However, given the combinatorial nature of the problem, the solver appears to 'hang' on N > 20.

I am now trying to implement a work-around solution.

The cubicles are sorted in descending order of minWidths. If the minWidths are equal, then they are sorted in descending order of their minHeights.
I then solve it using the [First Fit decreasing heuristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). This gives me an upper bound on the total panel width, and a list of present column widths.

Now I try to make the panel width smaller and try to fit my feeders in that smaller sized panel. (I am able to check whether the feeders fit in a given list of column widths in an efficient manner)

The panel width can be made smaller in the following ways:
1. Take any column, replace it with a column of next lower minWidth feeder. If the column is already of the lowest minWidth, then try to remove it and check.
2. Take any column, replace it with a column of a higher minWidth feeder and remove another column.
3. Any other way, I don't know shall be glad if anyone can point out.

I have implemented the 1st way correctly. Following is the code. However, I am not able put the other way in code correctly.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < columnVector.size(); i++ ) {

    QVector< Notepad::MyColumns > newVec( columnVector );
    if ( newVec[i].quantity > 0
         && ( i > 0 || newVec[i].quantity > 1 ) ) {

        newVec[i].quantity--;

        if ( i < columnVector.size() - 1 )
            newVec[i+1].quantity++;

        float fitResult = tryToFit( newVec, feederVector );
        myPanelWidth = fitResult ? fitResult : myPanelWidth;    

        if ( fitResult ) { // if feeders fit, then start the iteration again.

            columnVector = newVec;
            i = -1;    
        }    
    }    
}
```

Any help shall be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/21282418/2521214

- and swap x,y axises
- because that solution minimize page height (fixed page width)
- if you do not want border then set it to zero

it is basically what you are coding now